# How to print reverse for loop from right to left

Tags: java, android

How to print reverse for loop from right to left below is my for loop which displays value like this   I want to change output like mirror image value that show from left to right I want to show from  right to left see below:

```
int r;
int p;
r=31;
for (i = 0,p=r; i < week_no; i++,p--)
{
     HoyahCalendar.a[i / 7][i % 7] = String.valueOf(p); 
}
```

Output is like this

`31 30 29 28`

I want to show like

`28 29 30 31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to change

```
 for (i = 0,p=r; i < week_no; i++,p--)
```

To

```
 for (i = 0,p=r-week_no; i < week_no; i++,p++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize p to 28 and increment it with each iteration of the loop as follows:

```
int r;
int p;
r=28;
for (i = 0,p=r; i < week_no; i++,p++)
{
     HoyahCalendar.a[i / 7][i % 7] = String.valueOf(p); 
}
```